Converting time stamps in R to time id variable
I have a data frame in R that looks like that:
                ID Time
1                1 2023-06-17 21:00:00 CEST
2                1 2023-06-18 21:00:00 CEST
3                1 2023-06-19 21:00:00 CEST
4                1 2023-06-20 21:00:00 CEST
5                1 2023-06-21 21:00:00 CEST
6                2 2023-05-28 21:00:00 CEST
7                2 2023-05-30 21:00:00 CEST

So for each ID, I have measurements that were gathered at a certain time. The number of measurements differ across IDs. The first measurement for each ID differs as well. Measurements were one day apart.
I need to convert the measurements, so that a new variable "time_new" - provides a comparable time structure across all IDs, so that the new data frame would look like:
                ID Time                     time_new
1                1 2023-06-17 21:00:00 CEST        1
2                1 2023-06-18 21:00:00 CEST        2
3                1 2023-06-19 21:00:00 CEST        3
4                1 2023-06-20 21:00:00 CEST        4
5                1 2023-06-21 21:00:00 CEST        5
6                2 2023-05-28 21:00:00 CEST        1
7                2 2023-05-30 21:00:00 CEST        3

So I need a function that

sorts the available dates for each ID,
checks how long the dates were apart
allocates a new time variable to the ID

I have no idea and would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Questions in R do a lot better with a reproducible example. In this case, can you edit your question to include the output of dput(head(dat)), where dat is the name of your data frame? The way that your Time column is stored matters for a question like this.

library(data.table)
# setDT(mydata) if not already a data.table
mydata[, time_new := as.numeric((Time - min(Time, na.rm = TRUE))/(60*60*24) + 1), by = ID][]
#       ID                Time time_new
#    <int>              <POSc>    <num>
# 1:     1 2023-06-17 21:00:00        1
# 2:     1 2023-06-18 21:00:00        2
# 3:     1 2023-06-19 21:00:00        3
# 4:     1 2023-06-20 21:00:00        4
# 5:     1 2023-06-21 21:00:00        5
# 6:     2 2023-05-28 21:00:00        1
# 7:     2 2023-05-30 21:00:00        3

sample data
mydata <- data.table::fread("ID    Time
                1 2023-06-17T21:00:00 
                1 2023-06-18T21:00:00 
                1 2023-06-19T21:00:00 
                1 2023-06-20T21:00:00 
                1 2023-06-21T21:00:00 
                2 2023-05-28T21:00:00 
                2 2023-05-30T21:00:00")


You can avoid dividing by (60*60*24) by instead doing difftime(Time, min(Time), units = "days"). This also avoids any potential pitfalls if there happens to have been a leap second.

Order rows of data by ID and Time:
df <- with(df, df[order(ID, Time), ])

Create a new time column:
df <- transform(df, time_new = ave(as.integer(as.Date(Time)), ID, FUN = \(x) x - min(x) + 1))

Check
df
#   ID                     Time time_new
# 1  1 2023-06-17 21:00:00 CEST        1
# 2  1 2023-06-18 21:00:00 CEST        2
# 3  1 2023-06-19 21:00:00 CEST        3
# 4  1 2023-06-20 21:00:00 CEST        4
# 5  1 2023-06-21 21:00:00 CEST        5
# 6  2 2023-05-28 21:00:00 CEST        1
# 7  2 2023-05-30 21:00:00 CEST        3


Calculate the difference in dates, referencing the smallest date by ID.
print("Dummy data")

dat <- data.frame("ID"=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2), 
    "Time"=as.Date(c("2023-06-17 21:00:00","2023-06-18 21:00:00","2023-06-19 21:00:00","2023-06-20 21:00:00","2023-06-21 21:00:00","2023-05-28 21:00:00","2023-05-30 21:00:00")))
print(dat)
Date2 <- strptime(dat$Time, format="%b %d")

print("Calculating min date")
dateMin <- dat[ave(as.numeric(Date2), dat$ID, FUN = order) == 1, ]
dat2 <- merge(x=dat, y=dateMin, by = "ID", all.x = TRUE)
dateMinRef <- data.frame(dat2["ID"], "Time" = dat2["Time.y"])
print(dateMinRef)

print("Calculating difference in min date ID wise")
diffDate <- as.numeric(difftime(dat$Time ,dateMinRef$Time , units = c("days"))) + 1

dat$time_new <- c(diffDate)
print(dat)

Which gives following output
[1] "Dummy data"
  ID       Time
1  1 2023-06-17
2  1 2023-06-18
3  1 2023-06-19
4  1 2023-06-20
5  1 2023-06-21
6  2 2023-05-28
7  2 2023-05-30
[1] "Calculating min date"
  ID     Time.y
1  1 2023-06-17
2  1 2023-06-17
3  1 2023-06-17
4  1 2023-06-17
5  1 2023-06-17
6  2 2023-05-28
7  2 2023-05-28
[1] "Calculating difference in min date ID wise"
  ID       Time time_new
1  1 2023-06-17        1
2  1 2023-06-18        2
3  1 2023-06-19        3
4  1 2023-06-20        4
5  1 2023-06-21        5
6  2 2023-05-28        1
7  2 2023-05-30        3

I hope this is what is expected

A tidyverse approach with lubridate::date and dplyr::first:
(toy data at the end)
library(tidyverse)

new_df <- my_df %>% 
  arrange(ID, Time) %>% 
  mutate(
    .by = ID, 
    new_time = date(Time),
    new_time =  1 + as.numeric(new_time - first(new_time)))

Output:
> new_df
# A tibble: 7 × 3
     ID Time                new_time
  <dbl> <dttm>                 <dbl>
1     1 2023-06-17 21:00:00        1
2     1 2023-06-18 21:00:00        2
3     1 2023-06-19 21:00:00        3
4     1 2023-06-20 21:00:00        4
5     1 2023-06-21 21:00:00        5
6     2 2023-05-28 21:00:00        1
7     2 2023-05-30 21:00:00        3

Toy data:
# toy data
my_df <- tribble(
  ~ID,    ~Time,
  1, "2023-06-17T21:00:00",
  1, "2023-06-18T21:00:00",
  1, "2023-06-19T21:00:00",
  1, "2023-06-20T21:00:00",
  1, "2023-06-21T21:00:00",
  2, "2023-05-28T21:00:00",
  2, "2023-05-30T21:00:00")
  
my_df <- mutate(my_df, Time = ymd_hms(Time))

Created on 2024-05-21 with reprex v2.1.0

Simplest approach with timeplyr::time_id().
library(timeplyr)
time_id(mydata$Time, g = mydata$ID)
#> Assuming a time granularity of 1 day(s)
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 3

